# how to get the next date for a day of month

Tags: postgresql, date

thanks for reading, this is the situation

I have a current_date and a day of month, so i need to know what will be the next date for this day of month, having in mind that some month don't have 30 and 31.

**Example:**

- current_date = '2018-09-24'
- day_of_week = 31

**Expected result:** '2018-12-31'

Currently i have this:

```
create or replace function next_diff(vals int[], current_val int) returns int as 
$$
declare v int;
declare o int := vals[1];
begin
    foreach v in array vals loop
    if current_val >= o and current_val < v then
       return v - current_val;
    end if;
    o := v;
    end loop;
    return vals[1] - current_val;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and this:

```
create or replace function next_day_of_month(days_of_month int[], curr_date date) returns date as 
$$
declare cur_dom int := extract(day from curr_date);
declare next_diff int := next_diff(days_of_month, cur_dom);
begin
    if next_diff < 0 then
    curr_date := curr_date + '1 months'::interval;
    end if;
    curr_date := curr_date + (next_diff || 'days')::interval;
    return curr_date;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

but for this calling:

```
select next_day_of_month(array[31], '2018-09-24');
```

i am getting:

"2018-10-01"

**Extra example**

If i have this value

- current_date = '2018-02-01'
- day_of_week = 31

i will need the next month with 31th but i can't get '2018-02-31' because February don't have 31th then i should get '2018-02-31' because March have 31th.

**Conclusion**

if the month don't have the specified day must ignore the month and jump to the next.

thanks for all

**Final method**

Using Carlos Gomez answer, i create this PostgreSQL function and work perfectly:

```
create or replace function next_day_date(curr_date date, day_of_month int) returns date as 
$$
declare next_day date;
begin
    SELECT next_day_date into next_day FROM (
      SELECT make_date_nullable(EXTRACT(year from n.month)::int, EXTRACT(month from n.month)::int, day_of_month) AS next_day_date
      FROM (
        SELECT generate_series(curr_date, curr_date + '3 months'::interval, '1 month'::interval) as month
          ) n
      ) results
      WHERE results.next_day_date IS NOT NULL and results.next_day_date > curr_date  LIMIT 1;
      return next_day;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

just add other filter in where clause `and results.next_day_date > curr_date` to prevent get the same or previous values for specified date

Thanks everyone for helping

Thenks Carlos you are the best

Gracias carlos eres el mejor :)

Comment: Why can't you just add 31 days to the current date using an interval? What about 29th of February? (leap years) if current day is 29th of January in a non-leap year, what do you want as the result? (1st March?)

Comment: if i add 31 days i will not work because some months ends with 28th, 29th 30th and 31th, if the month don't have the specified day example 31th on  February the result must to jump to next month getting March 31th

Comment: mmm, my point was that you do NOT specify (in sufficient detail) what it is that you do want. There are a substantial number of standard date functions and adding "interval 1 month" is possible - so I (and others) are struggling to understand why you need a non-standard function. Note also that you didn't reply about leap years and February. You need to "specify" (in some detail, esp. for leap years) what it is you expect.

Comment: i just edit my question adding other example with more explanation

Comment: There is something wrong with this script - select next_day_of_month(array[31], '2018-09-22'); also gives me "2018-10-01" - which should not be the case.

Comment: A suggestion - Why don't you use a date dimension table with a incremental surrogate key, as if it were being used in a star schema.

Comment: if you are after "end of next month" then use `select date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'` **BUT** if you are trying to use **between** for date ranges - don't. see https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Comment: @MontyPython that is the problem with my current script select next_day_of_month(array[31], '2018-09-22'); try to get '2018-09-31' but don't exists then PostgreSQL turns into "2018-10-01" that why i should ignore months with out 31th (or whatever  specified day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your examples don't really match up but I think I know what you are trying to solve for (your first example result should be '2018-10-31' since October has 31 days and your second example result should be '2018-03-31'). It seems that given a date and a day of month you want to find the next month that has that day of month. To do this, I would do the following:

This function just wraps [make_date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) to let it return null since it throws an exception if a date given to it is out of bounds (like February 30).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_date_nullable(year int, month int, day int)
RETURNS date as $$
BEGIN
  RETURN make_date(year, month, day);
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN RETURN null;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This SELECT first generates the next three months starting with the current one, then makes date out of them with your provided `day_of_month` and finally gets the first one that isn't null (exists according to postgresql.

```
SELECT next_day_date FROM (
  SELECT make_date_nullable(EXTRACT(year from n.month)::int, EXTRACT(month from n.month)::int, day_of_month) AS next_day_date
  FROM (
        SELECT generate_series(current_date, current_date + '3 months'::interval, '1 month'::interval) as month
      ) n
  ) results
  WHERE results.next_day_date IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1;
```

Hope this helps!